# NodeJS fetch("https://www.google.com") says "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" but it was a 200

Tags: get, cors, axios

My Firefox developer network tab says that the call was a 200 and even shows the page, yet both `fetch` and `axios` say that it failed with a network error.

axios call was just ==>

```
    axios.get('https://www.google.com', {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        alert(response); 
    }, (error) => { 
            alert("error = " + error); 
    });
```

This has got to be something simple/stupid but I just can't figure it out.  :-(

Oh yeah.  Edge does the same thing . . . .

(EDITED) MORE DETAILS

If I add an UNBLOCK CORS extension to my browser *AND* comment out my two header lines, it works. With the header lines, it doesn't work -- so they must be wrong, but I don't see how.

i.e.

```
axios.get('https://www.google.com', {
    headers: {
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH'
    }
}).then((response) => {
```

works

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already discovered, the issue is that this is a cross-origin request and that is only allowed with CORS.

However, it seems you misunderstood CORS.

The whole point of the same-origin policy is that people should not be able to do what you are trying to do here - send a request in the browser from a page of domain A to a page of domain B. The only exception is when **B** (not A!) explicitly allows receiving requests from domain A (or from domain `*`).

So, in your case, **Google** (not you) would have to send those headers in the **response** in order to tell the browser that this request is permitted and it should return the results to your code. Of course, Google isn't doing that, so even though it is a 200, you never get the result because the browsers see that in that 200 response those CORS headers are missing.

The only way for you to make that work without relying on the extension to disable this mechanism (other than asking Google to add an exception for your domain ) would be to proxy this request through your server. If your *server* sends the request to Google and not the script in your page, it will work of course, since it's a policy that the *browsers* enforce, and the server is not inside a browser. So, you'd have to send a request to your server which would forward it to Google and then pass the response from Google back to your code in the page.

There seems to be some confusion on your end about what is sending the request though: In your question title you wrote "NodeJS" (which would imply sending it from the server already) but actually you are sending the request from the script in the browser (which is apparent since you talk about the *Firefox* network tab, and you use `alert` which doesn't exist in node.js, plus you talk about a browser extension), so the browser rules apply to you.

See also:

- https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9
- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/overview-of-proxy-server-and-how-we-use-them-in-react-bf67c062b929
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

---

Note: As for why it fails using the Unblock CORS extension with those headers attached (instead of the headers being just ignored), I'm not sure, but it is not relevant because in the *request* those headers are useless at best and invalid at worst anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  

Yeah, the question title was old.  I should have changed it.

I got faked out by the browser extension working on Google.  Reading their docs made it seem as if they just auto-added the headers, which would mean that my adding the headers should work equally well.  I now suspect that it intercepts the return and strips the CORS stuff (otherwise, it shouldn't work for Google as you point out).  I suspect that my adding headers tells the extension that I know what I'm doing and not to disable CORS.